# JBoss-as-distribution-6.0.0.Final password encryption

Tags: encryption, jboss6.x

I am trying to encrypt my database password 'an&&an123' using the below command

```
java -cp E:\Server\jboss-6.1.0.Final\lib\jboss-logging.jar;E:\Server\jboss-6.1.0.Final\lib\jbosssx.jar org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule an&&an123
```

But the command encrypts only the string before '&' that is it encrypts only 'an' and skips '&&an123'. I have followed instruction give in this link [Encrypting Data Source Passwords](https://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html)

Comment: try to put the parameter into quotes (or simple apos quotes)

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you. Putting & in double quotes worked.